# Set fadeout to timeout function which applies class to hide div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have added a loader on my page which does the animation for 3 seconds then a function applies styles to the animation to make it not visible. I want to add a fadeout effect when the 'waa' style is applied to the 'load' div.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('load').className = 'waa';
}, 3000);
```

```css
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
}

.waa {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading" id="load"></div>
```

https://codepen.io/ah5ann/pen/oNEBexm

Comment: Probably easiest if you add a `transition` for the `opacity` property.

Comment: Be aware that by doing `className = 'waa';` you also remove the class `loading`, which includes position and size. So even if a transition might happen, you would not see it. `className += ' waa';` or using [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) might be better options here.

Comment: @Lain I have added transition to the class 'waa' and it does not affect it

Comment: Yes, because `#load` has a height of zero.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to make sure you're using the proper method for adding the class:

```js
element.classList.add('your-css-class');
```

This will replace your current class of `loading`:

```js
element.className = 'your-css-class';
```

Then you can simply use the `transition`-property to make it fade out.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  element = document.getElementById("load");

  element.classList.add("waa");
}, 3000);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans);
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
  transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
}

.loading-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.loading-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Quattrocento Sans", sans-serif;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(1) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(2) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(3) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(4) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(5) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(6) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(7) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
}

@keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
}


}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.waa {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading" id="load">
  <div class="loading-text">
    <span class="loading-text-words">L</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">o</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">a</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">d</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">i</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">n</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">g</span>

    <div><span style="color:#fff;">made by ASN</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason that function does not apply 0 opacity/add the new class for me

Comment: `className` is a read and write property. While `classList` may be a better choice, your elaboration is inaccurate.

Comment: @Asn did you apply the transition to `.loading`? try using `console.log`, are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @SigurdMazanti to load because its getting element by id

Comment: @Asn could you paste a link to your current code into a jsfiddle/codepen and post the link here as a comment, it's hard to tell what exactly isn't working on your end. Either way, applying the transition to either `#load` or `.loading` shouldnt make a difference.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti I have added the link to my question

Comment: @Asn [Is this what you're looking for?](https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/dydNzOL) I added the JS from this answer and added  `.waa{opacity: 0;}`. There already was an opacity-transition on the `.loading`-element. If you want the transition to be shorter, just change the `animation-duration` associated with `opacity` in the `transition`-shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using js - why not just use a [keyframes animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes):

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quattrocento+Sans);
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: block;
  
  animation-delay: 3s;              /* run animation after 3s */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;    /* stop animation after it has run */
  animation-duration: 1s;           /* make animation run for 1 second */
  animation-name: fadeOut;          /* name of the animation to run - see below */
}

.loading-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.loading-text span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Quattrocento Sans", sans-serif;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(1) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(2) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(3) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.4s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(4) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.6s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(5) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 0.8s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(6) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 1s infinite linear alternate;
}

.loading-text span:nth-child(7) {
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
  animation: blur-text 1.5s 1.2s infinite linear alternate;
}


@keyframes fadeOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
}

@keyframes blur-text {
  0% {
    filter: blur(0px);
  }
  100% {
    filter: blur(4px);
  }
}


}
```

```html
<div class="loading" id="load">
  <div class="loading-text">
    <span class="loading-text-words">L</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">o</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">a</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">d</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">i</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">n</span>
    <span class="loading-text-words">g</span>
    <div><span style="color:#fff;">made by ASN</span></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>some page content</div>
```

If you want to continue to use js, then you would need to add a [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) to your loading class to animate the opacity

Comment: the problem with this is that its working, but the text in the div fades away and the whole div does not

Comment: You would have that problem with your transition anyway - as it's just a loading div that you don't need any interaction with, you can set the pointer events to none so once it's transparent, you can still interact with the page - see edit above

Comment: I have added a codepen link to the code in my question

Comment: @Asn see edit to answer snippet above

Comment: Ive got it to work but this also works thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

**style.css**

```
.loading {
    opacity: 1;
}

.waa {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 500ms linear;
}
```